# Highcharts stacked bar data from CSV

Tags: csv, highcharts

I'm trying to implement a stacked bar chart with data coming from a CSV.
I need to update **series:** with the data from the CSV file which contains, for example "John,10,5,3,4,1".
Help please!

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

UPDT

I finally got it working, but still there's a problem. The bars are inverted and I need them to be exactly in the same order as in the CSV file.

Here's my parser:

```
$.get('chart.csv', function(data) {
                            var lines=data.split('\n');
                            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                            var items = line.split(',');
                            var series = {
                                data: []
                            };
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo == 0) {
                                    series.name = item;
                                } else {
                                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                }
                            });
                            options.series.push(series);
                            });
                            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

The contents of the CSV file:

```
Disconnection,30,30
Site Care,12,12
Documentation,35,35
Lining,22,22
Connection,70,52
```

I need the stacked bars in the same order as in the legend:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EkHg.png

Comment: How your CSV and parser look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to custom setting the series indices before you render the chart to fix the inversion of the bars.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < options.series.length; i++) {
        options.series[i].index = options.series.length - 1 - i;
        options.series[i].legendIndex = i;
    }
```

Comment: I've already managed to getting working properly. The CSV file is now being generated in reverse order and the chart is now displaying correctly. Thank you anyway!